# While running the python manage.py getting this type of error

Tags: python, django

The django.db.backend is deprecated while running the manage.py .the site packages are not supporting

```
home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py:55: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Accessing django.db.backend is deprecated.
  res = instance.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(instance)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 197, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/devbase/devbase/queuearoo/main/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django_earthdistance.expressions import DistanceExpression
ImportError: No module named django_earthdistance.expressions
```

Comment: Can you share or check the corresponding lines of code from `settings.py` and `models.py` if you have created one ?

Comment: Can you do a `pip freeze` and verify if `django_earthdistance` is installed or not?

Comment: C(env) devbase@bounce:~/devbase/queuearoo$ pip freeze
attrs==18.2.0
Automat==0.7.0
cart==1.1.7
constantly==15.1.0
Django==1.11.16
django-earthdistance==1
Yes it is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `django_earthdistance.expressions` is part of package [django-earthdistance](https://pypi.org/project/django-earthdistance/) which seems to be not installed, please run

```
pip install django-earthdistance
```

to install it.

Comment: ^C(env) devbase@bounce:~/devbase/queuearoo$ pip install django-earthdistance
Requirement already satisfied: django-earthdistance in /home/devbase/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1)
Requirement already satisfied: django>=1.8 in /home/devbase/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django-earthdistance) (1.11.16)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /home/devbase/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django>=1.8->django-earthdistance) (2018.5)
You are using pip version 18.0, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: looks like its installed in a venv, make sure your are in venv while running manage.py